# Numpy Linalg norm behaving oddly (wrongly)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large vector F with a few million entries that gives this inconsistent behaviour when taking norms.

```
np.linalg.norm(F,2.000001)=3225.96..
np.linalg.norm(F,2)=inf
np.linalg.norm(F,1.999999)=3226.01..
np.linalg.norm(F,1)=inf
---------
np.linalg.norm(F)=inf
np.linalg.norm(F/12)=inf
np.linalg.norm(F/13)=246.25
---------
np.sum(F*F)=inf
np.sum(F*F/169)=60639
np.sum(F*F/144)=inf
---------
np.all(np.isfinite(F))=True
np.max(np.abs(F))=11
---------
F.dtype=dtype('float16')
```

Aside from some sort of hacky solution, does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: What does `np.sum(F*F)` give? What about dropping the second argument, `np.linalg.norm(F)`? What is `np.max(F)`? What is `np.isfinite(F).all()`?

Comment: @Eric I added the computations you asked for in a more clear format.

Comment: What is `F.dtype`?

Comment: `dtype('float16')`

Comment: Ouch... ```float16```. Probably not what norm was optimized for.

Comment: @Shakespeare `numpy.array([11 * 11 * 1e6], dtype='float16')` is infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the comments, your issue is that `float16` is too small to represent the intermediate results - its maximum value is 65504. A much simpler test-case is:

```
np.linalg.norm(np.float16([1000]))
```

To avoid overflow, you can divide by your largest value, and then remultiply:

```
def safe_norm(x):
    xmax = np.max(x)
    return np.linalg.norm(x / xmax) * xmax
```

There's perhaps an argument that `np.linalg.norm` should do this by default for float16

Comment: Eric, before I accept, could you perhaps explain why the $L_p$ norm with $p=1.999$ or $p=2.0001$ worked but the default $p=2$ doesn't?

Comment: @Shakespeare: What is np.linalg.norm(F,1.999999).dtype? And how does it compare to the `p=2` case?

Comment: It's float64. Thank you, kind stranger

Comment: @Shakespeare: There's something weird going on with type detection by numpy there, but it fails as expected if you use `np.linalg.norm(..., np.float16(1.9999))`

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Perhaps it'd be worth bringing this up with the numpy people?

Comment: You're speaking to one now ;). I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8775) to bring this up with the other numpy people though

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no fix from Numpy yet. So, for completeness, another (quite obvious) solution from my side for **calculating a norm**:

```
def calcNorm(vector):
    if (vector.dtype == np.float16):
        vector = vector.astype(np.float32)
    return np.linalg.norm(vector)
```

Or, as I needed it, in the use case of **normalizing a vector**:

```
def normalize(vector):
    prevType = vector.dtype
    if (vector.dtype == np.float16):
        vector = vector.astype(np.float32)
    norm = np.linalg.norm(vector)
    if (norm != 0 and np.isfinite(norm)):
        vector /= norm
    return vector.astype(prevType)
```